# How to read app.config values in C# Test Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I have a Project for which i am writing unit testing, I need to read values of app.config of project file in Test Project for which I dont want to copy app.config in my test project

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In test project choose add existing item, select app.config and check `add as link`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read settings by using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`.

If you don't want two copies of app.config but want the same settings for both projects, then you can add the file as a link